# Fatal errors - Reorganizing my Github

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm on ubuntu 14.04

I've been trying to reorganize my github but have run into some errors. I've created empty repos on github and am trying to populate them with all the files of the same folders I have on my local disk.

I go through these steps:

```
git init Java-Applications
git add -u
git commit -m "Update"
```

but once I enter

```
git push origin master
```

I recieve

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I update my newly created github repos with the ones I've created locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `origin` remote to your GitHub url.

Run this command:

```
git remote add origin (github url)
```

You probably didn't need to do this step when you were working this repo before because when you clone the `origin` remote is setup for you.

Once you have your `origin` setup you can pull/fetch/etc from GitHub. You will probably be out-of-sync with what is on GitHub, so if you are comfortable with rebasing a good way to get in-sync would be:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

Then, when you are ready to push your work:

```
git push origin master
```

[This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) is a good article on managing your remotes.

Comment: I tried doing `git remote add https://github.com/Alkarin`, then once I used `git fetch` I recieved `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Alkarin/' not found`

Comment: @Alkarin It looks like you didn't supply the full path to the repo. For example, for the "Java-Applications" repo use: https://github.com/Alkarin

Comment: @Alkarin but first, remove the incorrect remote that you added like this: git remote remove origin. Then run the "git remote add ..." command

Comment: Attempting to remove origin just returns `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. Also are you saying to use `https://github.com/Alkarin/Java-Applications`?  Note: when I run git remote -v it returns with the same error, and I recieve the same error when trying to add the url.

Comment: @Alkarin it looks like you are not in the repo... is your pwd at the root of the repository? Did you run git init?

Comment: @Alkarin also, after run git init did you make the initial commit? (git add .; git commit -m "initial")

Comment: With a bit of fumbling around it seems the root repos had the wrong origins set up. I used the commands you suggested, making sure the urls point to their specific url IE: for java applications the origin must be `https://github.com/Alkarin/Java-Applications`. I got it to work! Thank you so much and for bearing with me.

Answer (score 1):

`git init` is for creating a new repo. Since you're trying to add stuff to a repo that already exists, it would make more sense to `git clone` the (empty) remote into your local folder. When you push, the remote will already be there. (To do this now, you'll have to delete the .git directory -- you can't clone into a directory that has one.)

Alternatively, you can create the "origin" remote by hand, as Jonathan.Brink suggests.